# How to remove the bottom toolbar using css in mobile view?

Tags: magento2.1.5, toolbar, pager, category-view

In product listing page there are two toolbars one at the top of list as shown below:
[image]
another toolbar at bottom of list as shown below:

[image]

Both of them are has outer div as: `<div class="toolbar toolbar-products">`

I need to hide the lower one when in mobile devices. For that I'm planning to write css which hides the lower one. I need to add a class to any one of the div so that those two can be distinguished and apply different css for those two. How may I accomplish this?

Comment: You can add your custom class in the list.phtml file then add css @Purushotam

Comment: I did not find that in list.phtml . can you show me in answer? @Pranay K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like Vikas' method as if the element order is changed or `.products` is removed from the element you lose your styling.

#### A cleaner method:

Copy `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` into your theme.

On line `119` wrap `<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>` in your own div like this:

```
<div class="bottom-toolbar">
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
```

And then you can write your CSS targeting that class.

```
.bottom-toolbar {
    display: none;
}
```

### Even cleaner method

If you want to fully remove it just delete line 119 (`<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code in css.

```
.products + .toolbar.toolbar-products { display: none; }
```

Comment: you did not read question properly. I want to add a class to that second toolbar div.

Comment: bro check your question "How to remove the bottom toolbar using css in mobile view?" . you can use above code for this in media tag.

Comment: I did that. But  it is hiding both of the toolbars. Please check the description.

Comment: Did use `+` sign ?